# Eclipse OSGi Bundle Console Exception

Tags: eclipse, osgi

I am using Eclipse Juno to run the OSGi. But while running i am not able to see the console and getting the below error:

I'm trying to run my bundle as OSGI framework but i got the following output and i don't know where is the mistake:

```
!SESSION 2015-08-05 17:54:16.831 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_65
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -console -configuration runtime

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-05 17:54:17.182
!MESSAGE Could not find bundle: unknown
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not find bundle: unknown
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.ConsoleManager.checkForConsoleBundle(ConsoleManager.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:208)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-08-05 17:54:17.198
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.main(EclipseStarter.java:208)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need expose your services in the MANIFEST.MF, this file is located into META-INF directory, you can use this plugin of maven for do this work automatically:

http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html